# Circular dependency with typescript-sequelize between Customer and Address

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

```
//customer.model.ts
import { Address } from 'address.model.ts' 
//Customer class 
export default class Customer extends Model {
    @HasMany(() => Address)   
    public addresses: [Address];
}

//address.model.ts
import { Customer } from 'customer.model.ts'

//Address class
export default class Address extends Model {
    @Primary key
    @ForeignKey(() => Customer)
    @Column({ field: 'customerId' })
    declare customerId: number;
}
```

It shows this error
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Address' before initialization

It seems a circular thing, one call another, and stays in loop...

I tested both classes in one file and I was successful... but I need new options because if there is another class interacting with the address it doesn't seem right to keep it together with the customer...

I'm trying to associate the two classes each in their own file without any problem... using typescript-sequelize..